# How convolutional layer filter size affects input length and how to keep labels the same size

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, convolution

Assume we have a one dimensional convolutional layer in tensorflow.keras with input size of 100 (ignoring the batch and channel dimensions for simplicity), the kernel size is 51 (in reality it could happen by applying smaller filters in multiple layers) and we want to keep the length of output the same of input (padding=same). I would like to know what indexes will be filled with zero after applying the filter, would it be 50 most right ones or 50 most left hand ones or 25 on each sides. Also if I have a label per each element what would be the best way to reduce the number of labels to 50 to still best represent the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The padding is both sides, before applying the convolution, you can easily see this with this code of convolving ones with ones. (The expected result is the kernel size for the center)

```
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Input, Conv1D
from keras.models import Model

length = 100
filt = 51

ins = Input((length,1))
outs = Conv1D(1, filt, padding='same', kernel_initializer='ones', use_bias=False)(ins)
model = Model(ins, outs)

preds = model.predict(np.ones((1,length,1)))[0, :, 0]
print('result length = ', len(preds))
print(preds)
```

Outputs:

```
result length =  100
[26. 27. 28. 29. 30. 31. 32. 33. 34. 35. 36. 37. 38. 39. 40. 41. 42. 43.
 44. 45. 46. 47. 48. 49. 50. 51. 51. 51. 51. 51. 51. 51. 51. 51. 51. 51.
 51. 51. 51. 51. 51. 51. 51. 51. 51. 51. 51. 51. 51. 51. 51. 51. 51. 51.
 51. 51. 51. 51. 51. 51. 51. 51. 51. 51. 51. 51. 51. 51. 51. 51. 51. 51.
 51. 51. 51. 50. 49. 48. 47. 46. 45. 44. 43. 42. 41. 40. 39. 38. 37. 36.
 35. 34. 33. 32. 31. 30. 29. 28. 27. 26.]
```

Notice how it gradually decreases to the borders. These are the increasing number of zeros as the filters slides.

---

There isn't a clear answer to the last question. It depends on what you need to do. 
What does "best represent" mean? You can use a `Dense(50)`, would it work? It depends on what you want. You could reshape 100 to 50x2 and take a mean of the new axis.... there are really a lot of solutions, each one with its own properties.

Comment: That was my guess. Thanks for the great illustration. For me this is a time sequence of values for binary detection. I was thinking of stripping the labels sequence from both sides and keeping the 50 ones in the middle.

Comment: Maybe an `LSTM(units)` then a `Reshape((50,2*units))` then another `LSTM(whatever)` with a final `Dense(classes)`? --- This may also work with a `Conv1D instead of the LSTM, but I'd use short filters.

Comment: It's the labels sequence that was thinking to reduce its size. Would it be possible to use LSTM layers to that purpose?